# Is $\mathcal{L}_{M}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a linear subspace?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation, moment-generating-functions

Is the space $\mathcal{L}_{M}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ of of all random variables, $X$, whose moment-generating function  $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ a linear subspace of the set of all random variables ?

I dont think it is because if $X,Y \in \mathcal{L}_{M}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ then it does not need to be the case that $X+Y \in \mathcal{L}_{M}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.  But I cant think of any counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$Why not? One has using Cauchy-Schwarz:
\begin{align}
0\leq \E[e^{t(X+Y)}]=\E[e^{tX}e^{tY}]\leq \sqrt[]{\E[e^{2tX}]\E[e^{2tY}]}=\sqrt[]{M_X(2t)M_Y(2t)}<\infty
\end{align}
So $X+Y\in\mathcal{L}_M(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. We also have $\alpha X\in\mathcal{L}_M(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ that is even easier to prove. So $\mathcal{L}_M(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is a linear subspace.

Comment: Nice one - i was thinking it wasn't because X integrable, Y integrable does not imply XY integrable.  But this is exp(tX) and exp(tY).
Clearly I am not with it today (:

Comment: @Namch96 Thank you! Yes I can understand your cautiousness.